# How to parse a JSON containing string property representing JSON

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I have many JSONs with structure as followed.

```
{
    "p1":"v1",
    "p2":"v2",
    "p3":"v3",
    "modules": "{ \"nest11\":\"n1v1\", \"nest12\":\"n1v2\", \"nest13\": { \"nest21\": \"n2v1\" }  }"
}
```

How to parse it to this?

v1, v2, v3, n1v1, n1v2, n2v1

It is not a problem to extract "v1, v2, v3", but how to access "n1v1, n1v2, n2v1" **With Spark Data Frame API**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use the `DataFrameFlattener` implicit class [found](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/dataframes-datasets/introduction-to-dataframes-scala.html) in the official databricks site.

First you will need to define the JSON schema for the *modules* column then you flatten the dataframe as shown below. Here I assume that the file `test_json.txt`
will have the next content:

```
{
    "p1":"v1",
    "p2":"v2",
    "p3":"v3",
    "modules": "{ \"nest11\":\"n1v1\", \"nest12\":\"n1v2\", \"nest13\": { \"nest21\": \"n2v1\" }  }"
}
```

Here is the code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, DataFrame}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DataType, StructType, StringType}

implicit class DataFrameFlattener(df: DataFrame) {
  def flattenSchema: DataFrame = {
    df.select(flatten(Nil, df.schema): _*)
  }

  protected def flatten(path: Seq[String], schema: DataType): Seq[Column] = schema match {
    case s: StructType => s.fields.flatMap(f => flatten(path :+ f.name, f.dataType))
    case other => col(path.map(n => s"`$n`").mkString(".")).as(path.mkString(".")) :: Nil
  }
}

val schema = (new StructType)
  .add("nest11", StringType)
  .add("nest12", StringType)
  .add("nest13", (new StructType).add("nest21", StringType, false))

val df = spark.read
  .option("multiLine", true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
  .json("C:\\temp\\test_json.txt")

df.withColumn("modules", from_json($"modules", schema))
  .select($"*")
  .flattenSchema
```

And this should be the output:

```
+--------------+--------------+---------------------+---+---+---+
|modules.nest11|modules.nest12|modules.nest13.nest21|p1 |p2 |p3 |
+--------------+--------------+---------------------+---+---+---+
|n1v1          |n1v2          |n2v1                 |v1 |v2 |v3 |
+--------------+--------------+---------------------+---+---+---+
```

Please let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: Big thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is parse the JSON string to actual javascript object

```
const originalJSON = {
  "p1":"v1",
  "p2":"v2",
  "p3":"v3",
  "modules": "{ \"nest11\":\"n1v1\", \"nest12\":\"n1v2\", \"nest13\": { \"nest21\": \"n2v1\" }  }"
}
const { modules, ...rest } = originalJSON
const result = {
  ...rest,
  modules: JSON.parse(modules)
}
console.log(result)
console.log(result.modules.nest11)
```

Comment: Can you use JavaScript in a Databricks notebook?

Comment: I'm sorry i'm not familiar what that is

Comment: hey guys, it is not a problem to parse it in general, how to do it with Spark Data Frame API?

Comment: N1v1 is also accessible this way, no i dont know what that is can you expound what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

When you retrieve the "modules" element, you are actually retrieving a string. You have to instantiate this string as a new JSON object. I don't know what language you're using, but you generally do something like:

```
String modules_str = orginalJSON.get("modules");
JSON modulesJSON = new JSON(modules_str);
String nest11_str = modulesJSON.get("nest11");
```

Comment: The idea is that the doubly encoded JSON is stored as a string in the parent JSON structure. It isn't known to be encoded JSON except by you the encoder/decoder. SInce you *know* it's JSON you can convert it back into JSON (ie. remove the exit characters "\") structure by re-instantiating it as shown above.

Comment: it is not a problem to parse it in general, how to do it with Spark Data Frame API?